# Writing to a binary file NoSuchField Exception

Tags: java

```
ObjectOutputStream os = null;
try {
  os = new ObjectOutputStream (new FileOutputStream(fileName));
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

for (int i=0; i<firstModel.listOfItems.length; i++)
  try {
    os.writeObject(firstModel.listOfItems[i]);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is the first time I deal with binary files, and what I am trying to do is write all the objects I have from an array of Objects to the binary file I created but it doesn't work for some reason. I appreciate your help.

---

The `Model` class:

```
public class Model { 
    MenuItem[] listOfItems; 
    public Model(){ 
        listOfItems = new MenuItem[0]; 
    }
    /*
     * (More methods)
     */
}
```

Comment: post stack trace. Does the object you write implement Serializable?

Comment: Presumably `firstModel` doesn't have the field `listOfItems`.

Comment: @NiksTyagi its an object of a class called Model.

Comment: @bellabax yes it does implement Serializable.

Comment: @ooga I don't think so but anyways here's the class Model:
public class Model {
 
 MenuItem[] listOfItems;
 
 public Model(){
  listOfItems = new MenuItem[0];
 }
and it has more methods but they're not used where I am having the problem

Comment: @user3043419 Is your `Model` class in the same package as the other class?  If not, `listOfItems` won't be visible unless you make it public.  That might cause the exception, but we'd need to see a stack trace to be sure.

Comment: @NathanielJones if you mean if it is a subclass from the class MenuItem then it is not. I just tried listing listOfItems as a public field but that didn't work either.

Comment: @billy_b29 No, I wasn't asking if it's a subclass.  I was asking if `listOfItems` is [visible](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) to your method.